# Bluetooth enable and disable using ADB is not working in Android 7 Samsung galaxy Note 5

Tags: java, adb, appium, appium-android

We are trying to enable and disable Bluetooth before we start our automation test using adb commands

Enable

```
adb shell service call bluetooth_manager 6
```

Disable

```
adb shell service call bluetooth_manager 9
adb shell settings put global bluetooth_on 0 in db level
```

it is changing in the device db level but not reflecting in the device ui level so the test gets failed

We are getting the Bluetooth status using this command

```
adb shell settings get global bluetooth_on
```

Are there any other work around to enable and disable the bluetooth using APPIUM java because these commands working in some devices but not in all the device. I am looking for a permanent solution.

The same commands working in Android 5 (Lollipop)

Comment: Did you checkout the `driver.setConnection(Connection.wifi)` method?

Comment: No I didn't, I am looking to enable and disable bluettoth. Do setConection have a enum for bluetooth.

Comment: Yes, it does. Check it out. https://medium.com/@eliasnogueira/how-to-deal-with-network-connection-in-appium-4-0-0-2134021fac25

Comment: Actually it is not in the network connection it talks about WIFI,  AIRPLANE, ALL, NONE. There is no method for Bluetooth